# How to parse List of Values from a column of a file into Spark sql Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am still new to spark scala, i have a requirement to extract the first partition from every table in hive. I have extracted the table list in a separate text file and created as a sequence, i have no idea how to parse the each sequential value into "show partitions test_hive_database."

```
scala> import scala.io.Source
import scala.io.Source

scala> val filename = "text_tables.txt"
filename: String = text_tables.txt

Sample file containing the table list:
TABLE_NAME_A101
TABLE_NAME_A102
TABLE_NAME_A103
TABLE_NAME_B101
TABLE_NAME_C101

scala> val linestable = 
scala.io.Source.fromFile("text_tables.txt").getLines.toSeq
linestable: Seq[String] = Stream(TABLE_NAME_A101, ?)
```

Below is the sample first partition from a table and i have concatenated the table along with the partition value.

```
scala> sql("show partitions test_hive_database.TABLE_NAME_A101").withColumn("new_column",concat(lit("TABLE_NAME_A101,"),'partition)).select("new_column").show(1,false)

+------------------------------------+
|new_column                          |
+------------------------------------+
|TABLE_NAME_A101,dta_ld_dt=2018-01-23|
+------------------------------------+
only showing top 1 row
```

Tried with for comprehension

```
scala> for(e <- linestable) yield (sql("show partitions test_hive_database.$e").withColumn("new_column",concat(lit("$e , "),'partition)).select("new_column").show(1,false))

org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
extraneous input '$' expecting {'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD'
```

Expected Result

```
+------------------------------------+
|new_column                          |
+------------------------------------+
|TABLE_NAME_A101,dta_ld_dt=2018-01-23|
|TABLE_NAME_A102,dta_ld_dt=2018-02-28|
|TABLE_NAME_A103,dta_ld_dt=2018-03-31|
|TABLE_NAME_B101,dta_ld_dt=2018-04-30|
|TABLE_NAME_C101,dta_ld_dt=2019-01-30|
+------------------------------------+
```

Actual Result:

I am getting error and i am not sure this approach is correct.

How to parse single column values from a file into a spark sql (table name) and get the result appended into a csv file?

Comment: What do you mean by first partition?

Comment: @JamesZ, I am trying to parse each value from file into the spark sql query and get the first partition or the min date if i run select it will take time so trying to get from the show partitions. Could anyone please provide a gits on how to frame this , it could be helpful for me.